# Ruby - html tags are not converted to formatting tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, string-formatting, html

I have a simple form, where a user can write some text and this text will be send to his email. This process works fine, but I have a problem with the text, that user wrote - in the email is displayed following:

```
["sadgsdah\r\nsdh\r\ndsf\r\nh\r\nfdhdfhdfh\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nfdh\r\ndf\r\njh"]
```

why there are the brackets and the `\n` and `\r` chars?

Before than I give the variable with the content into the email template, I tried to do following:

> mess_body = params[:contact][:message].to_s.html_safe

But unfortunately this didn't help me... what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all

```
mess_body = params[:contact][:message]
```

returns a array, not a single thing. That is why you get the [" and "] around  the output.
you could get the first element like this:

```
mess_body = params[:contact][:message][0]
```

Furthermore \n\r are line endings of a text box. Assuming that the e-mail you're sending is HTML the \n\r should be replaced by <br> in the String

Comment: yes, I totally forgot for that array instead of string. But still have the problem about `\n\r` - they're just replaced by the white space, not by the new line - this is how I see that in the mailbox. But when I take a look at the log of the project, there are correctly displayed  `new line` tags...

Comment: If the text is going into an html message, newlines are converted are just spaces visually - to make html force a newline, you need a <BR> tag

Comment: @DGM you mean I have to manually convert `\n\r` chars to `<br />`?

Comment: Yes That is what you should do

Comment: yes, but don't reinvent it, use the rails helper I posted in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

To convert newlines to look right in html, use [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) to convert the text.